# implement usb slave on fpga

Tags: usb, fpga

I wish to attach a board camera and display to an fpga and have an interface to a pc implemented.

This would need to be at least usb2 speed for video.  What is necessary to implement usb on an fpga?  Are there any IC's I should consider?  Perhaps something like firewire would be better or even gigabit ethernet?

Comment: What capability are you trying to achieve not available in off-the-shelf USB webcams?  Or is it just a "see if you can" type learning project?

Comment: I'm attempting to do some augmented reality work so latency from the camera to the display is very critical.

Comment: That seems more likely to be a problem with the host usb bus, camera, and video drivers than with webcam hardware itself (at least if you choose a good one)

Answer (score 1):

No FPGA can do USB without an external chip. At a minimum, you will need a USB transceiver, e.g. from Phillips, and the power-detect circuitry.

Comment: Indeed... I am more concerned with the protocol support.

Comment: Actually, it has been done, just as it's been done **in software** on small micro-controllers.  But the buffer memory and complexity required for protocol support may make it a poor fit (especially with video-scale buffering requirements)

Answer (score 1):

Get developer borad form for instance [digilentic](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Catalog.cfm?NavPath=2,400&Cat=10&FPGA)  or just check schematics and demo source (downloadable) from there webpage

Comment: Some of these do have USB interface chips descended from the FX2 family, but look carefully - I remember at least one where the connection of that chip to the fpga was while probably workable, not very optimal for streaming lots of data as part of the bus was left unconnected.

Comment: It depends why does he need this. He said that best thing would be 1Gb ethernet. I admit that i have not implement ethernet, but i am sure that is not much more complicated as USB and have much more documentation (back in days there was only one poorly written book on USB harder to understand than standard). On the other hand there is http://opencores.org. I think that least frustrating way is starting from something that works.